# How to Pass Fabric Task name as Variable to execute()

Tags: python, task, fabric, execute

I have a situation where the name of the task to be executed comes in from a json as a String. More like `u'taskName'`

I am trying to execute tasks in this format:

`import fabfile
tn = mydict['taskname'] # this taskname is definitely present in the fabfile imported.
//do something so this works:
out = execute(tn) # This obviously doesnt work!`

I am aware that `execute` takes in a Task object.

Can someone help me in converting the string (in tn) into a Task object / or if my statement is wrong, Can someone help me in figuring out how to call that particular task present in the fabfile please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're receiving errors your execute statement called an object that isn't a function of used a string that isn't a task name. See this example for how this can work simply:

from fabric.api import *

```
@task
def foo():
    print "bar"


@task
def buzz():
    execute("foo")
    execute(foo)
```

Note that this is from the docs of [execute](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.9/api/coretasks.html#fabric.tasks.execute), that it will take a string (as long as that's a @task decorated function) or the function object (no decoration needed).

Runs like this:

```
$ fab -f test.py buzz
bar
bar

Done.
```

Also note that you don't get the output of the run from an `execute()` call. See again the docs section on the return value which is "a dictionary mapping host strings to the given task’s return value for that host’s execution run."

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This works as intended... However, when I use fabric from yet another Python script, there is a problem with the fabfile not being loaded (hence the tasks not being present)...

I need to investigate on the ```load_fabfile``` function defined in ```fabric.main```.

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: This solved the problem:

```
    #load the master fabfile to fill up the state dictionary
    from fabric.main import load_fabfile
    docs, callables, default = load_fabfile('fabfile.py')
    state.commands.update(callables)
```